# goback() does not work in react navigation v2

Tags: react-native

I for drawer I used the following code

home page code:

```
   export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Container>
                    <Header>
                        <Left/>
                        <Body>
...
                        </Body>
                        <Right style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <Button transparent onPress={() => {
                                this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
                                console.log('drawer');
                            }}>
                                <Icon name='menu'/>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                    </Content>
                </Container>
            );}
        }
```

Index code for my home page:

```
export default HomeScreenRouter = createDrawerNavigator({
     Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
     AboutUs: {screen: AboutUs}, 
    },{ 
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />, 
    drawerPosition: "right",
     initialRouteName: 'Home', });
```

Index code for my AboutUs page:

```
export default (DrawNav = createStackNavigator
    ({ AboutUs: {screen: AboutUs}, 
    },));
```

about us code:

```
export default class AboutUs extends React.Component {

        static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({

            header: (
                <Header>
                    <Left/>
                    <Body>
...
        </Body>
                    <Right>
                        <Button transparent onPress={() =>navigation.goBack(null)}>
                            <Feather name="arrow-right" style={[{fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold'}, styles.yellowColor]}/>
                        </Button>
                    </Right>
                </Header>
            )
        });
        render() {
            return (
                <Container>
                               ...
                </Container>
            );
        }}
```

This code did not have problem in version 1

But in version 2, the return button does not work

And when I use my phone's back button, the app closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

//Code from Page where device back button disabled

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

componentWillUnmount() {
BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
this.handleBackButton);
}

componentDidMount() {
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handleBackButton);
}

handleBackButton() {
return true;
}
```

//Code from Page where device back button works and a custom back button to go back to previous page

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
    this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
    this.handleBackButtonClick);

}

handleBackButtonClick() {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
    return true;
}
```

Button transparent:

```
 onPress={() => goBack()}
```